# Is there a way to plot multilines instead of dots in python on a 3D plotly plot?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to plot thicknesses with the variables x, y, z_base and z_top and z_single. Essentially I have two data types, thicknesses (z_base and z_top) and spot heights (no bounding surfaces, but this is most of my data). I want to plot these on the same graph with a combination of points and lines.

I can currently plot only one z variable at a time; is there a way to plot all my z variables at the same time (many Z to one XY without creating new rows?)

Also is there a way to plot multilines instead of two dots wherever there is a thickness?

This is what I started with:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(data, x='x', y='y', z='z_single',
color='Type')
fig.show()
```

I tried doing this with the hope that I could assign multiple columns to z, but it didn't work:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(data, x='x', y='y', z='z_base', z='z_top',
color='Type')
fig.show()
```

I have no idea how to approach multilines though!